# Protracktor vs. ocLazy Load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, oclazyload

At the moment I faced an issue when the project I am working with was refactored using **ocLazyLoad**. From my side, I am an Automation QA working with **Protracktor v.5.1.2** .

Before implementing above-mentioned feature I was successfully using protractor involving such option as

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

But now as the app downloads js bundles separately, protractor seems to recognize the end of Angular $http and $timeout tasks, when the first js bundle is loaded. Whereas the page still is not ready for further work, because it loads next lazy loaded bundle and I am getting such errors like:

```
No element found using locator
```

I have also tried

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

but this is basically the same as ignoreSynchronization if you see the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.1.2/lib/browser.ts)  .

Such approaches might seem to be efficient

`browser.sleep(5000);`

or

```
browser.isElementPresent(by.css('a[ui-sref="some.stateLink"]'));

var $registerLink = element(by.css('a[ui-sref="some.stateLink"]'));

expect($registerLink.getText()).toEqual('Register Now');
```

or

```
var elem = by.css('a[ui-sref="some.stateLink"]');
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return browser.isElementPresent(elem);
}, 5000);
var $registerLink = element(elem);
expect($registerLink.getText()).toEqual('Register Now');
```

but they make tests fragile and there are too much places in my code where I have to process it.

Did anybody face such a problem? Are there any better solutions in comparison to  ones I suggested? Thank you.